# What is the thermodynamic limit?

Tags: thermodynamics, definition

It might be a very stupid question but I have trouble to make it clear to my mind:

Could someone explain me in a sentence **what is the [thermodynamic limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit)**?

Comment: have you read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit)?

Answer (score 2):

It can be seen as a mere definition. It is used for many calculations and it yields reasonable results. It reads

$$T.L.\equiv N\to\infty,\,\,\ V\to\infty,\,\,\ \frac{N}{V}<\infty$$

That is, the assumption is that the final quantity remains bounded, which makes sense because it is the density $n$ and one expects it to behave that way, even intuitively. In any case you can find a more profound explanation almost anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The TD limit is just "$N\rightarrow\inf, V\rightarrow\inf ,N/V=1$" where $N$ is the number of particles in your TD system and $V$ its volume.